# taking lag and capping the values with mean in dplyr

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe in r

```
   name    date         month    year     hours
   SSI     01-01-2016   01       2016      2000
   SSI     02-01-2016   01       2016      1900
   SSI     03-01-2016   01       2016      2038
   SSI     04-01-2016   01       2016      2041
   SSII    01-01-2016   01       2016      2000
   SSII    02-01-2016   01       2016      2100
   SSII    03-01-2016   01       2016      2105
   SSII    04-01-2016   01       2016      2203
```

I want to calculate `lag of hours` for every name `group by` month and year.Which I can do it with following code

```
  df1 <- df %>% 
    group_by(name,year,month) %>% 
    mutate(running_hrs = hours- lag(hours)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

What I want is where `running_hrs` is greater than 24 or less than 0,I want to cap those values with mean of that month. I am doing following.

```
  new_df <- df%>% 
    group_by(name,year,month) %>% 
    mutate(running_hrs = hours- lag(hours)) %>% 
    mutate(running_hrs_new = ifelse(running_hrs > 24 | running_hrs < 0,mean(running_hrs),running_hrs)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

   name    date         month   year    hours   running_hrs running_hrs_new
   SSI     01-01-2016   01      2016    2000        NA         
   SSI     02-01-2016   01      2016    1900       -100            (3/4)
   SSI     03-01-2016   01      2016    2038        138            (3/4)
   SSI     04-01-2016   01      2016    2041        3                3   
   SSII    01-01-2016   01      2016    2000        NA           
   SSII    02-01-2016   01      2016    2100        100            (10/4) 
   SSII    03-01-2016   01      2016    2105        5                5   
   SSII    04-01-2016   01      2016    2110        5                5
```

Values should be replaced by mean of running hours less than 24 and greater than or equal to zero. I think we can use conditional mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

new_df <- df%>% 
  group_by(name,year,month) %>% 
  mutate(running_hrs = hours- lag(hours)) %>% 
  mutate(valid_running_hrs= ifelse(running_hrs < 24 & running_hrs > 0,running_hrs,0)) %>%
  replace_na(list(valid_running_hrs=0)) %>%
  group_by(name,year,month) %>%
  mutate(running_hrs_new = ifelse(running_hrs > 24 | running_hrs < 0, mean(valid_running_hrs), running_hrs)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```